# Join custom table with product attributes on custom attribute

Tags: zend-framework, magento

It's fairly simple - I have a table with a field that corresponds to certain custom product attribute.

```
+----+-----------+---------+---------------------+  
| id | from_user | to_user | first_contact       |  
+----+-----------+---------+---------------------+  
|  2 |         2 |       2 | 2012-10-26 18:24:30 |  
+----+-----------+---------+---------------------+
```

`to_user` corresponds to `profile_id` product attribute which is unique. Now, I need to join product attributes such as `status` and `url_key` of that product to my custom table. I get stuck at the very soon, since I don't know how to reference `profile_id` field in my join syntax. I could always rely on flat product table, but I'd like to make the script more robust so that it works even if flat product is off. I presume I should use `joinAttribute()` but I'm having trouble understanding how.

Thanks

Comment: POst some code if you want help :)